# Gitignore generated pdf but not all pdf

Tags: html, git, pdf, markdown, gitignore

In my project we have certain `markdownfiles` which are used to generate `pdf` and `html` with the same filename (just different extensions). I would like to gitignore those `pdf` files not other `pdf` files (which are not generated).

I know that I could manually unignore those files one by one, also I know I could designate a folder to be unignored. But I was looking for some kind of a pattern by which I could ignore the generated files, that would by itself ensure that the non-generated files are not ignored.

Comment: Do you have a pattern? Can you share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opened to naming these generated pdf files with a slightly different extension such as `.gen.pdf` instead of `.pdf`, this would give you the opportunity to differentiate these files with a pattern:

```
*.gen.pdf
```

which will ignore your `.gen.pdf` files and not the `.pdf` files while keeping all your files in the same directory.

---

[gitignore rules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) can't handle such a complex rule for which a file would be ignored only if another file with the same name but not the same extension exists.

If renaming your files is not an option, then you could also add an extra step in the script used to generate these .pdf files, which would simply append the name of the generated .pdf to the .gitignore.

Answer (score 5):

Generate it to specific folder/subfolder and ignore this folder by gitignore specification.
It is most simple and efective solution.

Comment: I know I could designate a folder to be unignored. But I was looking for some kind of a pattern by which I could ignore the generated files, that would by itself ensure that the non-generated files are not ignored. No offense but I am looking for a more effective solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a naming convention for your files that can be used to ignore them. If the filenames does not follow a pattern, you could do it as step pointed in his answer, save the `pdf` files to a specific folder and just ignore that folder in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I know I could designate a folder to be unignored. But I was looking for some kind of a pattern by which I could ignore the generated files, that would by itself ensure that the non-generated files are not ignored.

Comment: @Nikhil well, in that case Xavier's answer will do it